# raspberry pi 4 New uart configuration

Tags: gpio, pi-4

New raspberry pi 4 has uart on gpio 12 and 13 under ALT4.
how could a character device /dev/ttyS5 be created out of it?
Thanks

Comment: I would start by looking in `/boot/overlays/README`

Comment: I found the answer here...Thanks....https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244827